# Namenode UI - Browse File System not working in psedo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 0.20.2 in psuedo distributed mode (all daemons on single machine).
It's up and running and I'm able to access HDFS through command line and run the jobs and I'm able to see the output.

But I am not able to browse the file system using UI provide by Hadoop.

http://namenode:50070/dfshealth.jsp.. it shows version and cluster status.. When i click on browse filesystem its not showing anything. Is there any issue with this?

I'm able to list the contents using hdfs shell commands, and In Cluster mode it's working fine.

Only in distributed mode I'm not able to browse the file system.. any inputs on this is appreciated. I have installed hadoop1.0.0 in psudodistributed mode too, and facing the same problem.

Comment: Typically this stems from dns or hostname setup problems either with your dns not being able to see other nodes or with incorrect values in the hadoop config files.

Comment: HI, Its on single node and same node name is provided in config files. I am able access HDFS through commandline..

Comment: Is there any error at all, like a 404?

Comment: No, just blank page.. not showing anything.

Comment: am seeing a thread in forms.. http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/Namenode-UI-Browse-File-System-not-working-in-psedo-dist-cluster-td809541.html.. But there is no reply.  same problem am also facing.

Comment: It just shows Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.. When i click on Browse file System. In cluster mode ( where 2 data nodes) its working fine..

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
vi /usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
```

And change this line:

```
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
```

to

```
<value>hdfs://[your IP]:54310</value>
```

Add the hostname and IP of namenode into the hosts file of the system from where you are browsing the above URL. If not done, then on clicking "Browse the filesystem" link will fail.

Answer (score 1):

ok i was also facing same problem...

> first my namenode Storage ditectory was tmp folder so when i restart my machine all data is     lost.
>   so i changed my namenode storage directory to other location in my hadrdisk.
>   and than i was also facing same problem i cant browse my file system.
>   when i check permission of that folder there is no permission given to that folder and i was unable to change that permission.
>   **so i copied the hadoop folder from my tmp folder to my home folder and change my namenode storage directory to that folder in home dirctory.**

and my problem is solved.

Comment: Can you please edit your own answer to make it clearer for the viewers? It would be appreciated, if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
and change this
   hdfs://localhost:8020
to 
   hdfs://(your-ip):8020

then restart hadoop-datanode service

Check logs if this also doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my analysis. I'm having the same problem and I'm using AWS. the "Browse the filesystem" link points to nn_browsedfscontent.jsp.

nn_browsedfscontent.jsp typically does the following

1. fetch the datanode ip address
2. fetch the datanode port (50075)
3. redirect the request to the ipaddress:port.

In the case of aws, a server instance has private DNS (available only between instances) and public DNS (available to access externally, internet).

In step #1, the ip address fetched is the private DNS and not public dns
In step #3, the ip address:50075 is private dns:50075 which will fail as it is not accessible publicly.

I replaced the private dns:50075 with public dns:50075 and I was able to browse the filesystem contents.

My knowledge of javascript is very poor and so unable to modify the nn_browsedfscontent.jsp to solve this problem. Not sure if has already been resolved.