# JobTracker web UI - not working in psedo-distributed mode v 2.7.1

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.1 in psuedo distributed mode (all daemons on single machine). It's up and running and I'm able to access HDFS through command line and run the jobs and I'm able to see the output.

I can access http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview. it shows version and cluster status and can access hadoop file system.

I found one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925805/namenode-ui-browse-file-system-not-working-in-psedo-distributed-mode) and applied its accepted solution but that does not work for me. When I am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:54310, I am getting below error message

```
It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is 
not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks..

[image]

I am using MR2 and not able to track my job on 8088. When I run map reduce job, it submit the job on http://localhost:8080 and thats url is not opening to track the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use port 50030 if you are using MRV1 for YARN use port 8088 for accessing resource manager.

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. Can you help me locate files where this configuration is defined?

Comment: Hadoop was not properly configured that's why it was submitting job to different url... Thanks Harinder :)